# Bind DOM element from JSON in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, contextmenu

Basically I am trying to make a right click functionality which records comments on elements, the ones we can see in MS word, Adobe reader. Now after the comment is recorded, the element should be highlighted, and on hover, or click, it should show the name and comment recorded. I was able to make the custom contextmenu, and record the name and comment on click, but am confused, how do I bind the comments back to the element. An example of the object created is like this.

```
[class:"haseebtesting ng-binding",
content:"Leader Page 5",
elementType:"table",
entercomment:"Mesaage",
entername:"Aijaz",
id:"test 4",
nodeName:"TD",
selectedText:""]
```

This is my code. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ48oeBBDthtVqXMRJPy?p=preview
https://aijazkhan81.github.io/contextmenu/

Comment: You have your data in `arrayObjs`. When you apply click or hover event then you can use `arrayObjs` as scope variable and apply the same way you have done in right click open form i.e. using `ng-model`

Comment: Instead of pushing the values to an array, you can use map and acheive. Like, you are pushing it to array in addT $scope.arrayObjs.push(t); Instead of $scope.arrayObjKey = {}; $scoep.arrayObjKey[t.content] = t; And in the respective prevent directive element you can make like this <input type="text" ng-model="objectData.entername" placeholder="Enter name"
              title="{{arrayObjKey[objectData.content].enterComment}}"/>

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.